# Task queue in Django

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks

I've only heard about tools like Celery, but I don't know if it fits my needs and is the best solution I can have.

Imagine a game like Travian. We initiate building and we have to wait N seconds until the construction is finished. When and how should we complete the construction?

---

**Solution 1:** Check if there are active construction every time the page loads. If queries like that takes some time we can make them asynchronous. If there are some - then complete.

However, in this way we are constantly waiting for the user to reload the page. Sure, we can use cronjob to check for constructions to be completed from time to time, but cronjobs execute once in a minute or less often. Constructions / attacks etc. must be executed as precisely as possible.

---

The solution above works, but has some cons. What are better and *RELIABLE* ways to perform actions like those I mentioned.

Moreover, let's assume that resources needs to be regenerated at `X per hour` speed and we need to regenerate them very precisely and pretty often. How can I achieve this without waiting for the page to be refreshed?

---

Finally, solution shall work in Webfaction hosting or any other shared hosting. I've heard that Celery doesn't work in Webfaction or am I mistaken?

Comment: You can do a asynchronous calls from time to time, to synchronize frontend status with server status, so you really don't have to wait for user to refresh. Just don't do it too often, because it may be expensive. And of course - you may want to synchronize different parts of interface in different ways - e.g. call for actual amount of resources should be cheap and frequent, but building query may not be refreshed until the timers says, that it should be finished.

Comment: But if the building influences hourly resource production? For example if building is to be build after 10 minutes and it doubles resource production, but player does not refresh the page, therefore resource production doesn't double. I need to perform actions very precisely.

Comment: Then resource callback should also check if there are any buildings which were built in the meantime and calculate gain in steps (to/from the completion of the building). Note that 90% of events can be evalueted lazily - you just retrieve a stack of unprocessed events which have influence on requested action and compute them in right order. Of course - you need also some kind of scheduler, which protects you from events flood, but as long as you have only a few actions per request - it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, celery have periodic tasks with seconds: 
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html
Also you can run tasks in time with celery's crontab
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

Also if you need to check resources count I think it's common part for every request, so your response should looks like

```
{
   "header": {"resources": {"wood":1, "stone":500}}
   "data": {.. you real data shoud be here...}
}
```

You need to add header to response that will contain common information like resources count, unread messages etc and handle it properly on client.

To improve it you can use nginx + ssl + memcache backend.